# Ideal boundary of a surface

Tags: general-topology

Is there a difference between ***"ideal boundary"*** as in Kerekjarto's theorem and ***"ends"*** as in the usual topological sense? All I can see is that the former is applicable to bordered surfaces as well as open ones, whereas the latter is only applicable to open, non-compact surfaces. Though I may be very wrong...

Thanks.

Comment: Which theorem of Kerékjártó? I think he may have proven more than just one theorem in his life. It'd be great if you can either summarise the theorem or give a link to a standard reference on it.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean Kerekjarto's Classification Theorem for non-compact surfaces, then essentially the definitions are the same, at least according to the statement and definition of ideal points in [this review paper](http://emis.mi.ras.ru/journals/AMI/2005/konya.pdf). Perhaps one may say that Kerekjarto defined his notion only for surfaces, but that's a minor point.

If your definition of "ideal boundary" differs from that of the linked paper (p11), please edit the question and supply it.

Comment: Thanks, Willie! That is indeed one of the papers I read. I have also read [this one](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1963-106-02/S0002-9947-1963-0143186-0/S0002-9947-1963-0143186-0.pdf). Seems like Richards has expanded on the notion to classify the types of ends by a ***triple of spaces*** in *Definition 2*. I am not entirely sure that I understand this bit. Are there only countably many such triplets up to topological equivalence?

Comment: @Brian: you should probably ask that as a new question. This time make sure to include all the relevant definitions and try to make the question as self-contained as possible. Cheers.